# Scala.js code produced by 1.0.1 slower than 0.6.32

Tags: scala.js

I've been coding a small project using Scala.js:

https://github.com/ppgllrd/Algorithms.scalaJS.InfectiousDiseaseSimulator

I noticed that the Javascript produced by 1.0.1 compiler turns out to be quite slower than that produced by 0.6.32. Both of them can be accessed at:

https://ppgllrd.github.io/Algorithms.scalaJS.InfectiousDiseaseSimulator/0.6.32/

https://ppgllrd.github.io/Algorithms.scalaJS.InfectiousDiseaseSimulator/1.0.1/

My animations run slower for 1.0.1. This is specially noticeable when I use Firefox and set the population size parameter to its higher setting (1500). One can even notice that the initialisation of the algorithm (since you press Start until you see first frame of animation) takes much longer for 1.0.1.

I have compiled both versions in exactly same way (using Scala 2.13.1), the only difference being using `addSbtPlugin("org.scala-js" % "sbt-scalajs" % "0.6.32")` or `addSbtPlugin("org.scala-js" % "sbt-scalajs" % "1.0.1")` in my `plugins.sbt`.

Is this behaviour something to be expected? As 1.0.1 claims to provide better run-time performance, is there anything in particular I'm doing in my code which could be responsible for this loss of performance?

Comment: If it's especially noticeable on Firefox, it could be the use of ES 2015 by default in 1.x. You could try to add `scalaJSLinkerConfig ~= { _.withESFeatures(_.withUseECMAScript2015(false)) }` in your project's `settings`, then `clean` and recompile, to isolate that factor.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. That seems to be the issue. I've uploaded resulting Javascript for those settings at https://ppgllrd.github.io/Algorithms.scalaJS.InfectiousDiseaseSimulator/1.0.1.noES2015/ and it runs much better.

Comment: I turned my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is especially noticeable on Firefox, it could be the use of ES 2015 by default in 1.x. Firefox' performance for ES 2015 is less than optimal, although using ES 2015 allows great code size reductions and an improved debugging experience.

You can force Scala.js 1.x to emit ES 5.1 (like Scala.js 0.6.x) with the following sbt setting:

```scala
scalaJSLinkerConfig ~= { _.withESFeatures(_.withUseECMAScript2015(false)) }
```

to be added in your project's `settings`. Make sure to `reload` and `clean` before testing anew.